# Call Web API using jquery AJAX in ASP.NET MVC 5 getting error Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, model-view-controller

Web API Using JQuery AJAX In ASP.NET MVC 5 getting error "Invalid or unexpected token"

I have created a Web API project with MVC. Which contains HomeController having Action method index

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

For above action method I would like to show employee details from ajax call in javascript alert message as

```
@{ 
Layout = null; 
} 
<script src="~/Script/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>  
<html> 
<head> 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" /> 
<title>Index<title> 
<head> 
<body> 
    <div><h2>You Are On View</h2><div> 
</body> 
<script> 

$(document).ready(function () { 
    $.ajax({ 
        type: 'GET', 
        url: "http://localhost:802/api/Employee/GetEmployee?Id=101", 
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
        dataType: "jsonp", 
        success: function (data) { 
            alert(data); 
        }, 
        failure: function (data) { 
            alert("Failure: "+ data); 
        }, 
        error: function (data) { 
            alert("Error: "+ data); 
        } 
    }); 
});
</script>
</html>
```

Also I have created one api controller as follows, which will return employee details

```
public class EmployeeController : ApiController  
{  
    public Employee GetEmployee(int Id)  
    {  
        Employee objEmp = new Employee();  
        objEmp = ; // get data from service   
        return objEmp;  
    }  
}
```

I am getting error like "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token" in console.

If I click on the error in console then I am getting my result as

```
{ "EmpId": "101","Name": "Rupesh" }
```

What I have tried:

I tried below solutions
1) http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/call-web-api-using-jquery-ajax-in-asp-net-core/

2) added headers as well & made changes in dataType from json to jsonp

```
dataType: "jsonp",
headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
```

3) Also I tried

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "http://localhost:802/api/Employee/GetEmployee?Id=101", true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
{
    if (xhr.readyState == 4)
    {
        alert(xhr);
    }
}
xhr.send();
```

4) Also added headers as

```
"Access-Control-Allow-Headers":"Content-Type",
"Access-Control-Allow-Methods":"GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS",
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
"cache-control":"no-cache"
```

Comment: The problem is because you're returning JSON, not JSONP. Change the `dataType` property in your `$.ajax` call. You also don't need CORS if you're making a local request. I'd suggest using a relative path for your AJAX request too

Answer (score 1):

This option in your `$.ajax` call.

```
dataType: "jsonp"
```

This tells that the response of this ajax call is coming from a cross domain jsonp call. jsonp is usually used for making cross domain ajax request. In the case of `$.ajax` method, it will send a query string for the callback method to the server and the server is expected to wrap the result in that string (like a method call). With $.ajax, you can provide your custom local js method as the callback in the `jsonp` option parameter.

When the result comes back for the `$.ajax` jsonp call, jQuery will try to parse it with the expectation that the result is a string where the result is wrapped inside the callback method name. But since your server is returning raw json (without any callback prepending), the code is failing.

Ideally if you are making the call to the web api endpoint of same app, you do not need the jsonp type. Also since you are not sending any data in the request body, no need to specify the content type.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var url="http://localhost:802/api/Employee/GetEmployee?Id=101";
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        failure: function(data) {
            alert("Failure: " + data);
        },
        error: function(data) {
            alert("Error: " + data);
        }
    });
});
```

You might also consider using `Url.RouteUrl` helper method to generate the route url to your endpoint (the method works in razor files)

```
var employeeUrl = "@Url.RouteUrl("DefaultApi",
                                new { httproute = "", controller = "Employee"})";
var url = employeeUrl + "/101";
//use url  for your call
```